# Adding a new line in "string.join()" when formatting arrays?

Tags: c#, arrays, datagridview, formatting

Hello I am a newbie programmer, I am trying to format arrays in a way where there is a line break at the end of a specific set of arrays. I currently have 4 separate arrays in which I want to arrange each item in the array to a specific pattern. I have accomplished this task but now I am stumped because they are all in one line. Let me give you an example: (I am doing this on a datagridview by the way)

```
(This is what I want to happen)
Binder Clips Small  pc      12         1260
Selleys All Clear   pc      12         2400
```

```
(This is what I am getting)

Binder Clips Small  pc      12          1260        Selleys All Clear      pc    12     2400
```

This is my code:

```
//I get these from a datagridview
            var items = carto.Rows
            .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
            .Select(x => x.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Trim())
            .ToArray();

            var units = carto.Rows
            .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
            .Select(x => x.Cells[2].Value.ToString().Trim())
            .ToArray();

            var quantity = carto.Rows
            .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
            .Select(x => x.Cells[6].Value.ToString().Trim())
            .ToArray();

            var prices = carto.Rows
            .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
            .Select(x => x.Cells[8].Value.ToString().Trim())
            .ToArray();

            //this is what I use to sort out the pattern that I want the arrays to be in
            string[] concat = new string[items.Length * 4];
            int index = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
            {
                concat[index++] = items[i];
                concat[index++] = units[i];
                concat[index++] = quantity[i];
                concat[index++] = prices[i];
            }

// and this is where I am stuck because I can just put \n, it would ruin the format even more
            cartitems.Text = string.Join(" ", concat);
```

I also tried doing something like this:

```
            int j = 0;
            string str = "";

            foreach (var item in concat)
            {
                str += item;
                if (j <= concat.Length - 1)
                {
                    if (j % 3 == 0)
                        str += " ";
                    else
                        str += "\n";
                }
                j++;
            }
```

It kinda gets the job done but the line breaks are all over the place.
This is what my projects look like so you can get a better gist on where am I getting the data from the 4 arrays:
[image]

basically the product name, unit, quantity and line total
and lastly I am storing in on a label so I can see how it the formatting looks like:
[image]

that about sums up my problem, I really hope you can help a newbie like me out, I have a feeling the answer is quite simple and I am just un-experienced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, you should keep your *data structures* (how the data is stored, implemented here as an array of values) separate from the data *representation* (in this case, written to a list box).

C# is an object-oriented language, so we might as well take advantage of that, right?

Create a class for your items.

```
class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; }
    public string Quantity { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }

    override public string ToString() {
        return $"{Name} {Unit} {Quantity} {Price}";
    }
}
```

This is how you load your array.

```
Item[] concat = new Item[items.Length];
int index = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++) {
    concat[index++] = new Item { 
        Name = items[i], 
        Unit = units[i], 
        Quantity = quantity[i], 
        Price = prices[i] 
    };
}
```

and this is how you can add the list of items to a listbox.

```
foreach(Item item in concat) {
    listBox.Items.Add(item);
}
```